# How to use the keyword this in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner javascript student , I have a problem with understanding the main goal of the keyword `this` and how to use it .

Please can anyone help me with examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this.show()` will call method show() if such is implemented in the object. `$len=this.len` will check the len field of object referenced by `this`. It is used to reference the object currently being in context.

Comment: [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742) covers the use of `this` quite thoroughly.

Comment: ^^ That book is amazing.  Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *this* keyword is a reserved keyword that, in general, is bound to an object.

When *this* appears in the body of a function, the object that is referenced by *this* usually depends on how the function was called.

There are many subtle details that can be found on [MDN.this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Frequent accepted usage that you will encounter (beware, this is not always the case depending on ... the context) :

- when dealing with object methods, *this* references the current instance
- when dealing with DOM events, *this* references the DOM element in the context of the event